# Password and sign up code

Tags: python

I am writing code for a sign up and password system. however, after the first registered person is written in to the file the next person who registers will also be written into the file but when it comes to logging in they can't.
please ignore the print('') gaps and the time pauses.

```
import time
def register():
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    print('')
    password = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
    print('')
    file = open("accountfile3.txt","a")
    file.write(username)
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(password)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    if login():
        print("You are now logged in...")
    else:
        print("You aren't logged in!")
def login():
    x = False
    while x == False:
        username = input("Please enter your username: ")
        print('')
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        print('')
        for line in open("accountfile3.txt","r").readlines(): # Read the lines
            login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            return True

        break
    print("Incorrect credentials.")
    print('')
print('Hello')
print('')
time.sleep(1)
print('This is python_workspace')
print('')
time.sleep(1)
print('These are the choices available: ')
print('')
print('|' + '-'*24 + '|')
print('|    1. Register         |')
print('|                        |')
print('|    2. Login            |')
print('|                        |')
print('|    3. Exit             |')
print('|' + '-'*24 + '|')
y = True
while y == True:
    choice1 = input('Please enter the number: ')
    print('')
    if choice1 == '1':
        register()
        break
    elif choice1 == '2':
        login()
        break
    elif choice1 == '3':
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect input, please enter either: 1, 2, 3')
        print('')
```

Comment: Your intent is to write a password in plaintext into a txt file?

Comment: is your indentation correct?, why is your `while` for?

Comment: It looks like the `if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:` block is not indented correctly.

Comment: Also, what dfundako said. I hope this is just a toy program for a homework exercise, or similar. Please do **not** do this for a real login system.

Comment: i am having a quick laugh out of this... plaintext password storage... :D

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the indentation when looping through the text file. It is only reading one line that's why its failing. I've fixed it in the code below. However storing usernames and password like this probably isn't the best idea, I would advise using a database for this. Whenever dealing with passwords as well they should be hashed using a strong hashing function. Also validation on the username is quite important, for example the username could have a space in so it won't read the password properly.

```
import time
def register():
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    print('')
    password = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
    print('')
    file = open("accountfile3.txt","a")
    file.write(username)
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(password)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    if login():
        print("You are now logged in...")
    else:
        print("You aren't logged in!")
def login():
    x = False
    while x == False:
        username = input("Please enter your username: ")
        print('')
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        print('')
        for line in open("accountfile3.txt","r").readlines(): # Read the lines
            login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
            if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
                print("Correct credentials!")
                return True

        break
    print("Incorrect credentials.")
    print('')
print('Hello')
print('')
time.sleep(1)
print('This is python_workspace')
print('')
time.sleep(1)
print('These are the choices available: ')
print('')
print('|' + '-'*24 + '|')
print('|    1. Register         |')
print('|                        |')
print('|    2. Login            |')
print('|                        |')
print('|    3. Exit             |')
print('|' + '-'*24 + '|')
y = True
while y == True:
    choice1 = input('Please enter the number: ')
    print('')
    if choice1 == '1':
        register()
        break
    elif choice1 == '2':
        login()
        break
    elif choice1 == '3':
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect input, please enter either: 1, 2, 3')
        print('')
```

Comment: thx that was very helpful, i will also take in your advice about storing the username and password

Answer (score -1):

Recommend you use a 3rd party authentication service. Take a look at this offering from Auth0 for example.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/python/01-login

Comment: Is this really necessary. OP is evidently a completely new learner. Providing that link as additional information is great, but as a standalone answer I find it to be completely unhelpful.

Comment: @EricChen1248, in most cases I would agree with you.

But when it comes to authentication, I strongly believe no one, especially a beginner, should build their own. 

The original post indicates this code is going to into production. The  code presented is dangerous.  

It would be much better for the OP to spend time learning how to use a reliable third party service.